# listing 3.9 of Michael Hartl rails tutorial does not load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

## My Problem / Question

I am unable to run the very basic rspec test in listing [3.9](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code-home_page_content_spec) I feel like I am missing something very basic which is causing the static_pages_spec to return a LoadError. Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong?

## The Error

> E:\CSProj\RailsTutorial\sample_app>bundle exec rspec spec/request/static_pages_s
>   pec.rb
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec
>   /core/configuration.rb:780:in `load': cannot load such file -- E:/CSProj/RailsTu
>   torial/sample_app/spec/request/static_pages_spec.rb (LoadError)
>          from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
>   1.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in`block in load_spec_files'
>          from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
>   1.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
>          from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
>   1.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in`load_spec_files'
>          from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
>   1.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
>          from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
>   1.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in`run'
>          from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
>   1.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'

## The Code

I am using the following code: https://github.com/adoliver/sample_app/blob/static-pages/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      page.should have_content('Sample App')
    end
  end
end
```

## Some information about my development environment

Windows 7
Used railsInstaller
Using windows native command line
Previous steps in the tutorial worked.

E:\CSProj\RailsTutorial\sample_app>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]

E:\CSProj\RailsTutorial\sample_app>rails -v
Rails 3.2.9

### My bundles:

E:\CSProj\RailsTutorial\sample_app>bundle list
Gems included by the bundle:

- actionmailer (3.2.9)
- actionpack (3.2.9)
- activemodel (3.2.9)
- activerecord (3.2.9)
- activeresource (3.2.9)
- activesupport (3.2.9)
- arel (3.0.2)
- builder (3.0.4)
- bundler (1.0.22)
- capybara (1.1.2)
- childprocess (0.3.6)
- coffee-rails (3.2.2)
- coffee-script (2.2.0)
- coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
- diff-lcs (1.1.3)
- erubis (2.7.0)
- execjs (1.4.0)
- ffi (1.2.0)
- hike (1.2.1)
- i18n (0.6.1)
- journey (1.0.4)
- jquery-rails (2.0.2)
- json (1.7.5)
- libwebsocket (0.1.6.1)
- mail (2.4.4)
- mime-types (1.19)
- multi_json (1.3.7)
- nokogiri (1.5.5)
- polyglot (0.3.3)
- rack (1.4.1)
- rack-cache (1.2)
- rack-ssl (1.3.2)
- rack-test (0.6.2)
- rails (3.2.9)
- railties (3.2.9)
- rake (10.0.2)
- rdoc (3.12)
- rspec (2.11.0)
- rspec-core (2.11.1)
- rspec-expectations (2.11.3)
- rspec-mocks (2.11.3)
- rspec-rails (2.11.0)
- rubyzip (0.9.9)
- sass (3.2.3)
- sass-rails (3.2.5)
- selenium-webdriver (2.26.0)
- sprockets (2.2.1)
- sqlite3 (1.3.5)
- thor (0.16.0)
- tilt (1.3.3)
- treetop (1.4.12)
- tzinfo (0.3.35)
- uglifier (1.2.3)
- websocket (1.0.3)
- xpath (0.1.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You report:

```
load': cannot load such file -- E:/CSProj/RailsTu torial/sample_app/spec/request/static_pages_spec.rb (LoadError)
```

I don't know if this is silly, but the specs in my directory tree are in `/app/spec/requests`, not `app/spec/request`.